# How to make website authorization using curl and php?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to realize a simple authorization using login and password. I get a cookie but not sure if authorized or not (how to check?), also I am trying to redirect after authorization but as a result, I get Error 404 after my code tried to redirect (followlocation, true).

Here's my php code

Trying just to redirect but 404 occurred.

```
  $curl = curl_init($url);

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  $result = curl_exec($curl);

  echo $result;
  curl_close($curl);
```

And here's trying to authorize, not sure if it works (but I get cookie and in header I get 200 OK)

```
$loginData = [
    urlencode('j_username') => 'someName',
    urlencode('j_password') => 'somePassword'
];


$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 2);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($loginData));

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/authCookie.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/authCookie.txt');

$result = curl_exec($curl);

echo $result;
curl_close($curl);
```

Also, I use urlencode but not sure if I use it in the right way (I have it in curl like $curl --location --request POST 'http://someFullName' \ --data-urlencode 'j_username=someUsername' \ --data-urlencode 'j_password=somePassword')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for auth you can use http basic auth it very simple in use for client and server, client code in this case will be look like:

```
<?php

const COOKIE_FILE = '/tmp/authCookie';

$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'login';
$password = 'pass';

$ch = curl_init($host);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, sprintf('%s:%s', $username, $password));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIE_FILE);

$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

about your 4xx error, i think you have problems with server, for test redirections you can do something like:

```
<?php
//stable route with redirect
$host = 'https://bitly.is/EnterpriseButton';
$userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0';

$curl = curl_init($host);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
//with enabled followlocation
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

var_dump($result);

$curl = curl_init($host);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
//with disabled followlocation
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

var_dump($result);
```

and for check auth work you can auth through browser with cookies from curl